# Having some conceptual trouble creating a View to list users that have nodes containing entity references

Tags: entities, views

Users on my site can create content by adding a new node of content type 'project'.

Projects are assigned to exhibitions through a drop down 'exhibition' field which is an entity reference to another content type named 'exhibition'.

Exhibitions are created by admins and each exhibition has a location field (one of three distinct values).

I would like to create a view that displays all users that have created projects for two or more locations. So that could be (for example) 5 projects for 2 exhibitions in location X and 2 projects for 1 exhibition in location Y.

Having some conceptual trouble putting the view together, any help much appreciated.

Danny.

Comment: `5 projects for 2 exhibitions` does this mean the user didn't assign an exhibition for 3 projects?

Comment: Would an integer field on the user suffice? Your question makes it sound like rules could ++ an integer if conditions were met. A view could then filter based on that. If not, it's a very interesting question.

Comment: Actually, the title of your question is pretty different to your question. Could you clarify a bit please?

Comment: '5 projects for 2 exhibitions' - for example 3 projects in one exhibition, and 2 projects in the other.

Comment: Sorry have fixed the title (hopefully). 

An integer field combined with rules is a possibility i hadn't considered. That could possibly do it. I wil investigate that. 

I am using Drupal to handle applications to collaborate with a a network of galleries. It's working really well but I now want to begin to build out some views that give us some insights about people using the platform. 

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got around my mental block.

1. Created a 'Users' view.
2. Added an 'Entity Reference: Referenced Entity' relationship.
3. Turned on aggregation for my view
4. Added the field I wanted to count and selected COUNT (distinct)

Working well now.

Danny.